# How to get part of string from the end in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

I am making application where I receive a string from user. The string is concatenated with - character between them. First part of string contains alphabetic data whereas later part contains integers or floating point numbers. For example: A string might be 3 Cups Tea-5.99.I want to get the later part of string 5.99 separated by - character. How to do that? I know about PHP substr() function but that takes fixed characters to retrieve substring from. But in this case the later part will not be fixed. For example: 2 Jeans-65.99. In this case I would need last 4 characters meaning that I can't use substr() function. 
Anybody with solution? 
I know I would need to apply regex but I am completely novice in Regex. 
Waiting for your help. 
Thanks!

Comment: please, stop and think about what you're doing. Are you absolutely sure that sending around strings separated by `-` are your best tool for the job? what if you get a string like `3 kit-kat tablets-12.00`? have you ever heard of JSON?

Comment: Yeah. You are right, thought if this, that is why I asked I want to take the string from end to the point where first occurance of "-" takes place. Heard of JSON but I am to PHP only. What would be the solution then if user enters 3 kit-kat tablets-12.00?

Comment: JSON isn't relegated to javascript only. it has plenty of use inside PHP too, that's why we have `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`. Also, the very fact that the user has to manually type `3 kit-kat tablets-12.00` is a bad design. You need to have 3 different input fields (quantity, product and price) and then send them through a form. HTTP then will properly handle the transmission of these values and you won't need to do any string manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

```
$result = explode('-', $string)[1];
```

For PHP<5.4 you'll have to use temporary variable:

```
$data = explode('-', $string);
$result = $data[1];
```

*Edit*

As mentioned in comments, if there is more than 1 part, that will be:

```
$result = array_pop(explode('-', $string));
```

Comment: Not sure that would work. Explode takes the delimiter first, afaik ..?

Comment: That's all about mess with implode/explode .. thank you (first one accepts args in any order)

Comment: If the input can contain more then one dash use end() instead of hardcoding it to the second part.

Comment: @Darsstar fair enough. But `end()` is not needed since `array_pop()` exists

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Thank you very much for your answer as it handles the possible scenario of - occuring more than once.

Comment: array_pop() also seems to take a reference, array_slice(explode('-', $string), -1) would be the/a version without creating a new variable, right?

Comment: @Darsstar your point is correct. Both `array_pop()` or `end()` will produce `'Strict standards'` notice, but result will be ok (in PHP4, PHP<=5.0 there will be, however, a fatal error). Your version with `array_slice()` isn't good since it will return array and not a string inside it

Answer (score 1):

```
$bits = explode('-', $inputstring);
echo $bits[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos):

```
$str = '3 Cups Tea-5.99';
echo substr($str, strpos($str, "-") + 1);
```

Output:

```
5.99
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/54828)

Comment: @user2885137: No worries :)

Answer (score 0):

If data will be like this: "1-Cup tea-2.99", then

```
$data = "1-Cup tea-2.99";
$data = explode('-', $string);
$result = $data[count($data)-1];
```